# Why is it allowed to break up $\frac{v\,\cdot\,w}{\|v\|\|w\|}$ as $\frac{v}{\|v\|}\cdot\frac{w}{\|w\|}$, where "$\,\cdot\,$" is the dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I see in Strang *Linear Algebra* (Ed 5) the cosine formula:

$$\frac{v\cdot w}{\left \| v \right \|\left \| w \right \|} = \cos\theta $$

In one of the problem set answer key, a solution implies that:

$$\frac{v}{\left \| v \right \|} \cdot \frac{w}{\left \| w \right \|} = \frac{v\cdot w}{\left \| v \right \|\left \| w \right \|}$$

If it were all simple scalar multiplication, $\frac{ab}{cd}$, I see you can break it up like that, but it wasn't clear to me that I can break up a dot-operation in the same way.

What's the argument that allows me to say this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all $c\in \mathbb{R}$ and $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have the following two dot product properties:
$$(cv\cdot w)=c(v\cdot w)$$
and
$$v\cdot w=w\cdot v.$$
So in your case, we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{v}{\|v\|}\cdot\frac{w}{\|w\|}&=\frac{1}{\|v\|}(v\cdot\frac{w}{\|w\|})&\text{(first property)}
\\ & = \frac{1}{\|v\|}(\frac{w}{\|w\|}\cdot v) & \text{(second property)}
\\ & = \frac{1}{\|v\|}\frac{1}{\|w\|}(w\cdot v) & \text{(first property)}
\\ & = \frac{1}{\|v\|}\frac{1}{\|w\|}(v\cdot w) & \text{(second property).}
\end{align}$$
So this gives the desired equality. You probably won't need this level of rigor if this is an introductory linear algebra class, but I am trying to show how you would deduce the result with minimal axioms/rules, which is a relevant skill if you go on to take harder proof-based classes. Also, after having done enough similar calculations, it will probably become much more obvious to you.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for.  I couldn't see easily how to convert original equation to second equation.  Your approach of convert second equation into first equation (using those two simple rules) made it eminently clear.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well on the numerator it is just the dot product and they are divided by scalars. And the following property holds for dot product. $$\vec A.(\lambda \vec  B) = \lambda (\vec A.\vec B) $$. You can take scalars out of the dot product or take dot product of scaled vectors.